# Covergence in $\mathscr{L}^q $ implies convergence in $\mathscr{L}^p $ when $1 \le p \lt q \le \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

It is given that the measure $ \mu(X) \lt \infty$, and $1 \le p \lt q \le \infty$. The problem has two parts, whereas in the first part where we need to show that $ \mathscr{L}^q \subseteq \mathscr{L}^p  $ is clear to me.

It was given that a function sequence $ f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mathscr{L}^q $, we are supposed to show that $ f_n \rightarrow f$ in $\mathscr{L}^p $, where I assume that I should use the subset property, but I am not very clear with the method of starting the proof itself.

Comment: So you need to prove an inequality like $\|f\|_p \le C \|f\|_q$ for some constant $C>0$.  Perhaps your proof of the first part actually proves this.

Comment: @GEdgar I proved it without the constant, where I basically used the property that $ (\int |f| ) ^a \le \int |f|^a $ for $ 0 \lt a \le 1$, is there a way that I can do something with the constant over there? I showed that the q-norm of f is smaller than the p-norm. Maybe I did something wrong there?

Comment: You only said $\mu(X) < \infty$ in your hypothesis, and in that case $\|f\|_p \le C \|f\|_q$ is false without a constant.  If $\mu(X) = 1$ then it holds with constant $1$.